# Hiding status bar not working Swift 3, Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, statusbar

Set Target/General/Deployment info to Hide status bar.
Set None for Status Bar in VCs in storyboards.
Added the following code to all VCs.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Briefly hides status bar but immediately reappears.

Comment: "Set Target/General/Deployment info to Hide status bar" Irrelevant! "Set None for Status Bar in VCs in storyboards" Irrelevant! Stop thrashing. Only your implementation of `prefersStatusBarHidden` matters.

Comment: Tried that first, is not working. Split VC, added to master and detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the `prefersStatusBarHidden` of the root-level view controller matters — here, the split view controller. The split view controller wants a status bar; it gets a status bar. That is all that matters.

You could try subclassing UISplitViewController, setting `prefersStatusBarHidden` in your subclass, and using that subclass in the app.

Comment: Done! Should have thought of that.

Comment: Checking Hide status bar in Target/General/Deployment info does hide the status bar in the LaunchScreen because it sets "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES in info.plist.

Comment: @agent86 So that must be why it vanished and then reappeared, good point.

Comment: Yes. Thanks again